# Dont post parameter if null laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a price filter form with a `minprice` and `maxprice` when both parameters are filled in it works fine. But when only 1 is filled in I get an `InvalidArgumentException` error. This is due to one of the parameters being null. 
How do I allow a single parameter to pass through?

Form:

```
        <form action="/" method="post" class="form-inline">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail2" value="£-£">
                <input name=minprice type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 col-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2">
                <input name=maxprice type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 col-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $products = product::all();

        $pricefilter = (new product)->newQuery();

        if ($request->has(['minprice', 'maxprice']))
        {
               $pricefilter->where('price', '>=' ,$request->minprice);
               $pricefilter->where('price', '<=' ,$request->maxprice); 
               $products = $pricefilter->get();            
        }
        elseif ($request->has('minprice'))
        {
               $pricefilter->where('price', '>=' ,$request->minprice);
               $products = $pricefilter->get();            
        }
        elseif ($request->has('maxprice'))
        {
               $pricefilter->where('price', '<=' ,$request->maxprice);
               $products = $pricefilter->get();            
        }

        return view ('index', compact('products'));
    }
```

Comment: In the first if clause you have `$products = ...` and in the others you have `$product = ...`. It it some kind of typo?

Comment: what error you are getting in invalid argument exception??

Comment: @AlekosDordas Hello, fixed that but the same problem still remains

Comment: @zahidhasanemon since both parameters are passing through the error flags up on whichever value is null

Comment: I second zahid's comment. But you can actually get rid of the first `if`. Change the two `elseif`s to `if`s. Remove all `$products = $pricefilter->get();` and include it right above return view. Maybe see if it works for you after these changes?

Comment: @user3532758 Hello, if I do this am I only able to focus either $maxprice or $minprice and not both.

Comment: You'll be focusing on both. If it works for you I'll add an answer explaining in more detail.

Comment: @user3532758 Everything performs the same way but I still get the same error when submitting either just the minprice or just the maxprice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the if loops to use the isset method worked. 
I also reformatted the loops as **user3532758** suggested in the comments

> user3532758: get rid of the first if. Change the two elseifs to ifs. Remove all $products = $pricefilter->get(); and include it right above return view.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $product = products::all();

    $pricefilter = (new products)->newQuery();

    if (isset($request->minprice))
    {
           $pricefilter->where('price', '>=' ,$request->minprice);
    }
    if (isset($request->maxprice))
    {
           $pricefilter->where('price', '<=' ,$request->maxprice);                 
    }

    $product = $pricefilter->get();        
    return view ('index', compact('product'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and do some house cleaning around here.

```
public function index () {
    if(request()->has('minprice') || request()->has('maxprice') {

         $filter = Product::query();

         if(request()->has(['minprice', 'maxprice']) {

              $filtered = $filter->whereBetween('price', [request('minprice', 'maxprice']);

         } else if(!request('maxprice')) {

               $filtered = $filter->where('price', '>=' request('minprice'));

         } else if (!request('minprice')) {

                $filtered = $filter->where('price', '<=', request('maxprice'));
         }

          $products = $filtered->get();

    } else {
         $products = Product::all();
    }

    return view ('index', compact('products'));

}
```

Comment: One thing, you have to take note of, (not as important though) is your `Product::all()` statement. this will be called whether there are filters or not. Hence when one is filtering, it even takes longer than when loading all results.

Comment: *"Let's try and do some house cleaning around here."* - This is not an acceptable description of your answer. Please explain what you've changed and why. This is essentially a code dump with a catchy headline.

Comment: Hello, I'm getting a syntax error  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` relating to 
`$filter = Product::query();`